# Packages in R are failing to load

Tags: r

Whenever trying to load *any* package I get the following error (tidyverse is just the example in this case)

```
> library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'tidyverse':
 .onAttach failed in attachNamespace() for 'tidyverse', details:
  call: NULL
  error: package or namespace load failed for 'ggplot2' in library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib):
 DLL 'glue' not found: maybe not installed for this architecture?
```

In this particular error the problem seems to be with "glue", the issue is if I uninstall the glue package and reinstall it then try and load tinyverse again it will just tell me there is a problem with a different package... and repeat. Each time one package is reinstalled the error changes to something else.

It may be worth noting we use a central repository for packages and a user tells me this issue started to occur after installing the RISCA package.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Tried to uninstall and reinstall the problem packages however it just changes each time with a new problem package.

Comment: What version of R are you running? If you look at `.libPaths()` is your primary library source your own personal R directory? Have you recently updated or installed other packages than `RISCA`? What exactly is the central repository you are using?

Comment: @MrFlick > .libPaths()
[1] "\\\\numerus.local/azuredata/Shared/Numerus/R-Libraries"
[2] "C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/library"

No other packages installed or updated other than RISCA and above is the libPaths output. All packages are installed to the UNC path and then a environmental variable has been added to the system to point to it. 

Tested in R4.2.1 & R4.2.3

Comment: I vaguely remember hearing that R had issues with reading packages from network paths. Could you try configuring a local package library path and trying again? Furthermore, ‘tidyverse’ has in the past had [persistent installation issues](https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyverse/issues/70) due to package version conflicts. I *think* the issue was resolved but it might have cropped up again.

Comment: Oh. Having a shared library path is a very unsafe idea. It will lead to a lot of problems especially if people might be running different versions of R. That's probably what's leading to the different architecture warnings.

Comment: @MrFlick thanks for the info. What would you recommend we do for an RDS environment? We have two RDS servers so sometimes a package would be installed on one and not the other so I moved it to a central location. Would using a mapped network drive still cause issues rather than a UNC path or will it have the same consequence? Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, changing the UNC path to a mapped drive still did not resolve the issue. However, our UNC path was hosted on an Azure Files share, once I moved the library to a network location on our LAN everything seemed to just start working again.